# nmap recognizes android device not in a scan area of more than 3 ips

Tags: networking, android, nmap

this page was recommended to me by stackoverflow 
therefore I ask my question again here.

I have performed some nmap scans, yet I have found out, that the scan over a larger area provides more results than over a small area. (Multiple testing)

online Devices:
192.168.178.30 (Android smartphone)
192.168.178.31 Windows PC.

nmap-sS 192.168.178.29-31 (scan 3 IPs)
Result: 2 devices online (30,31)

nmap-sS 192.168.178.30-32 (scan 3 IPs)
Result: 2 devices online (30,31)

nmap-sS 192.168.178.25-40 (scan over> 3 IPs)
Result: 1 device online (31)

nmap-sS 192.168.178.28-31 (scan over> 3 IPs)
Result: 1 device online (31)

The same result I get with the other scanning methods (-sT, -sU, ...)

Is there any fix for me at a scan over the entire range to get all devices?

Comment: could you try with -P0 (ping scan)?

Comment: I have seen this behavior before with nmap regardless of target. Small IP range scans can produce different results and I never knew why.

Comment: Do you get improved results when you add `-T2`? This will slow the scan down; you may be sending too many packets for your connection, especially if it is wireless or certain virtual NAT connections.

Comment: Welcome to [security.se]. Please do not [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23951768/10080). In any event it is not a good fit here, I am migrating to [su].